# i want to get the record where column name equals to row record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

[image: Table]

above is the table and record i am using, in the below table i want to retrieve value 3 that is 11-20 column and row 11-20.

could any one help me please.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Comment: You are mixing data and metadata. SQL works best with relational data.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT [11-20] FROM ProductLines Where ProductLine='11-20'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 11-20 FROM tablename WHERE ProductLine = '11-20'
```

Comment: I look at SQL type tagged questions and look at them. I haven't answered here because Blazes is correct and I would add no value. if you choose to follow the same questions as me, it's up to you. Now, are you going to delete this untested and wrong answer?